# How do I get my server(AWS EC2) to send a .html file as an html in C#?

Tags: c#, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I have a server set up using Amazon Web Service's EC2 virtual machine.

My server application I have written in C#.

Currently, my game, written in JavaScript, can send data to the server and receive JSON objects when requesting data for the highscore board. This has all been working fine.

I decided to try and host my game from the server. For some reason though, if you request the index.html file, what the clients browser interprets is raw text. As you can see here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/19B04.png), it is displaying the index.html file as text, and it is simply putting it in the clients body under a 'pre' tag.

I originally thought it was a security thing, but I cannot find anything in the security of my EC2 instance that wouldn't allow it. Also, when I host it using localhost:8080 via Visual Studio, I have the same thing, which leads me to believe it is in my code.

Also, it is worth adding I went through my regedit and made sure all .html stuff is type "text/html".

In C#, after determining what the user was trying to request (which I know works, since it did fetch the proper html file), it calls the following method.

```
private static Response IndexRequest()
    {
        String file = "C:\\Game\\index.html";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
        reader.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
        fs.Close();

        return new Response("Play", "text/html", d);
    }
```

This method essentially reads the index.html file and changes it into a byte array for sending, then returns a an object with status Play, of type "text/html" which contains that array.

What calls that method receives a object Response with that data. That object Response is then told to call its post method, which looks as follows.

```
public void Post(NetworkStream stream) {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}\r\nServer: {2}\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Length: {4}\r\n",
            HTTPServer.VERSION, status, HTTPServer.NAME, mime, data.Length));

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

Where 
HTTPServer.VERSION == "HTTP/1.1",
HTTPServer.NAME = "HarbourGuide HTTP Server V0.1" 
and status/mime/data are the three things returned as the parameters from the first method (in this case, "Play","text/html", index.html's data as a bbyte array.

As I said, what this results in is the client receiving the data as text. Changing the mime to just "html" does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.